# Find the equation of the circle..

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Find the equation of the circle which passes through two points on the $X$ axis which are at distances $4$units from the origin and whose radius is $5$units.

My Attempt:

As per the question, if we let the points as $A$ and $B$, then these will be the point of contact of the tangets $OA$ and $OB$, with $OA=OB=4$units.

Then what should I do? Please suggest further.

Comment: By $O$, you mean the origin?  But the origin is inside the circle, clearly.  (the chord $AB$ passes through the origin).  Hence neither $OA$ nor $OB$ are tangents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let the center be $O$ and the two points that the circle passes through be $A$ and $B$. Since we know that $OA=OB$, what line do we know that $O$ is on? Where on the line must it be for $OA=OB=5$?

Comment: What are $OA$ and $OB$, radii or tangents?

Comment: @user354073 Radii - since $O$ is the center and $A$ and $B$ are on the circle.

Comment: How do I find the co ordinates of the points $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @user354073 You're given that they're on the $x$-axis and $4$ units away from the origin - that should do it.